# Resource Allocation - Two resources on one task at different ratios

Tags: ms-project

I have a project where I am setting resources at 60% availability in general.  However, for certain tasks, I would like to divide the work proportionally between two resources.  The best way I can describe it is with an example.

Say I have a 100 hour task.  I have it set to Fixed Work.  I have two resources, Tim and Bob, each set at 60% availability.  Tim is only responsible for 10% of the work for this task, leaving Bob 90% of the task.

I can manually assign 10 hours to Tim and 90 hours to Bob using the Task Usage view, but for a schedule with several hundred lines, this can get tedious.  Is there a way to select multiple tasks and ration them out like I want?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be quicker and easier to granulate this task to show what each of the resources are working on?

Underneath your current task, create two indented tasks, one for each resource. Set Work to 10 for Tim and 90 to Bob.

The higher level task will have the rolled up value of 100. You can set Work Complete on each resource individually and track what each of them has to do.

Comment: We've been trying to minimize the number of tasks, but I can definitely see the advantage in taking your route.  I'll mention it to my supervisor/coworker and see what he thinks about it.  Thanks for the suggestion.